# symbol and decimal number true in php

Tags: php, arrays, conditional-statements

I have script like this

```
$number = range(0, 9);
```

when I have condition like this

```
if (in_array('@', $number) === true) {
    echo "true";

}else "false";
```

and output:

```
true
```

and my question is why the symbols is the same whit any number in array $number??
I want symbols just symbols not number.

example I want like this

```
if (in_array('@', $number) === true) {
    echo "true";

}else "false";
```

output :

```
false
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation for `in_array()`:](http://php.net/in_array)

> If the third parameter strict is set to `TRUE` then the `in_array()` function will also check the types of the needle in the haystack.

In PHP, casting any string that doesn't begin with a number evaluates to to 0. The 0 exists in your array, so `in_array()` returns true. If you don't want this to happen, set the third parameter for `in_array()` to true, so it performs a strong comparison (equivalent to `===`) and consider the types, too.

```
if (in_array('@', $number, true) === true) {
    echo "true";
}
else { 
    echo "false";
}
```

Output:

```
false
```

Comment: hy thanks for the answer. and if I have  condition like this get true because in array @number have 0 . and when if comparison whit any symbols.