# symbols == 0 true in php

Tags: php, conditional-statements

I have script like this

```
if('@' == 0){
        echo "true";
    }else{
        echo "false";
    }
```

output :

```
true
```

the question is why it get true and how to get it false?
thanks.

Comment: The answer is [Loose Typing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

Comment: But what part of the answer to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22917618/symbol-and-decimal-number-true-in-php) don't you understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Mark Baker stated in the comments, PHP uses weak typing. According to the comparison matrix that you find here (http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php), the expression involving the string `'@'` compared to `0` will be evaluated as `true`.

Change your condition to:

```
if('@' === 0){
    ...
```

in this case you'll get `false`.

Answer (score 0):

For this condition to get `true` of `false` properly, you need to compare the value and the type of the operators. Try this:

```
if('@' === 0){
        echo "true";
    }else{
        echo "false";
    }
```

You will get `false` for this case.