# Array for required fields PHP

Tags: php

Problem:

```
if (empty($_POST) === false) {
        $required_fields = array('year', 'semester', 'title', 'number', 'handout', 'weight', 'handout', 'handin', 'feedback', 'brief', 'sub_details', 'add_note');
        foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
            if(empty($value) && in_array($key, $required_fields) === true) {
                $errors[] = '<p class="warning">Fields marked with an asterisk are required</p>';
                //var_dump($_POST);
                break 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Output section:

```
else if (empty($errors) === false) {
        echo output_errors($errors);
    }
```

I'm performing some validation on a form, however I am getting an error when outputting my errors array, even if the fields are entered and aren't empty, I still get the error appearing. I've tried changing the empty($value) to isset, however it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: What errors do you get? EDIT: Nvm. retard me.

Comment: Check `$key` inside your if condition for which post field its coming into it.

Comment: Try changing `in_array($key, $required_fields)` to `in_array($key, $required_fields, TRUE);` so it does type-strict comparisons instead of loose ones.

Comment: Why are you looping through all the contents of $_POST? If you really mean to ensure that each field in $required_fields is present, you should iterate over the contents of $required_fields!

Comment: One more thing: are you testing from a browser in such a way that you are actually passing parameters to PHP via $_GET, or do you really have a form which properly submits via $_POST?

Comment: @AmalMurali that worked. I'm not 100% sure how - what do you mean by 'loose' ones?

Comment: and even more beautiful would look like: (!empty($errors))

Comment: possible duplicate of [symbol and decimal number true in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22917618/symbol-and-decimal-number-true-in-php)